# How can one list item have 2 indexes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

Suppose that I write a list:

`foo=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1]`

When I try to find out the index of `1` in `foo`, it comes out to be 0. But I wanted to find the index of the `1` at the last ( it’s expected index is 9 ) so I wrote this simple code that would give me all the indexes of all the items in the list:

```
for i in foo:
  print(foo.index(i))
```

The result is:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
0
```

Notice that the last `1` in foo also has an index of zero according to the above iteration.

Now I try to delete the list item with an index 9 by using:
`del foo[9]` and the last`1` gets deleted even though the iteration proved that it has an index 0!

Why is this happening?

Comment: `1` is just a number, when passed to `index()`. And `index()` will search the complete list (up to and) for the first occurrence of that number. The second `1` in your list is, therefore, nothing special, and identical to the first `1`.

Comment: i would suggest to try using different numbers first before you test same numbers,because that will behave differently if the last 1 was a different number

Comment: "... the last 1 gets deleted even though the iteration proved that it has an index 0! " That is incorrect: you've only shown that the number 1 first occurence in the list is at position 0, and in your loop, you've actually shown that twice (because `1` comes along twice in your loop).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use the `index()` method it returns you the first instance of occurrence of the searched item.
Have a look at this

```
>>> a = [5, 4 , 1 , 3 , 1 , 2]
>>> a.index(1)
2
```

This will not change no matter what you do and how many times you iterate.
You can instead use

```
for index, item in enumerate(foo):
    print(index)
```

Answer (score 3):

To get all the indices:

```
>>> [i for i, num in enumerate(foo) if num == 1]
[0, 9]
```

To get the maximum index:

```
>>> max([i for i, num in enumerate(foo) if num == 1])
9
```

Answer (score 2):

In Python, if an item is found the iteration exits and doesn't check for others.

So if you call the index function with the element who's index you have to find. The index function will only retrieve the first element's index that it finds matching your argument (in this case, i)

If you want all possible indexes you need to use a [list comphrehension](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk)

```
foo=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1]
bar = [i for i,x in enumerate(foo) if i == 1]
print(bar)
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at the documentation for the `index` function:

> ```
> list.index(x[, start[, end]])
> ```
>
> Return zero-based index in the list of the first item whose value is `x`. Raises a `ValueError` if there is no such item.

So it returns the *first* item with that value. That explains why `index(1)` always comes out to 0.

When you use `del foo[9]`, you're telling it to erase the object at position 9 of the list. Although it has the same value as element 0, it is not the same object. We can prove this by doing

```
>>>foo[0] is foo[9]
False
```

This is expected behavior. Just because two objects have the same value does not mean they are the same object.

Answer (score 1):

`index()` searches from the beginning of the list, and returns once find. so index of `1` is 0. one solution is to enumerate yourself.

```
def index_all(lst, x):
    return [i for i, v in enumerate(lst) if v == x]

print(index_all([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1], 1))
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem,you are giving passing i as an argument to the function index
and the documentation says index(x) "Return the smallest i such that i is the index of the first occurrence of x".
so every time you pass 1,it will always give the first occurence
but check this

```
foo=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
>>> for i in foo:
...   print(foo.index(i))
... 
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

this yield different results because all elements are distinct

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way:

```
foo=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1]
for i, val in enumerate(foo):
    if val == 1:
        print(i)

'''
output :

0
9

'''
```

Answer (score -1):

If you do not understand, see the following source to explain.

```
1. help(list)  
2.  
def index(self, value, start=None, stop=None): 
    """
    L.index(value, [start, [stop]]) -> integer -- return first index of value.
    Raises ValueError if the value is not present.
    """
    return 0
```